# Python: Converting Pseudo-code to code

Tags: python, pseudocode

I tried coding these lines:

```
copy the first {ceiling of} n/2 points of P to array Pleft
copy the same {ceiling of} n/2 points from Q to array Qleft
copy the remaining {floor of} n/2 points of P to array Pright
copy the same {floor of} n/2 points from Q to array Qright 
m = P[ ({ceiling of} n/2) - 1].x
```

And I got:

```
mid = len(P) / 2

Pl = P[:mid]
Ql = Q[:mid]
Pr = P[mid:]
Qr = Q[mid:]
m = P[:mid - 1].x
```

But I do not know how to code this line:

```
copy all the points of array Q for which |x - m| < d into new array S[0..num - 1]
```

Please help.

Comment: You need `math.abs()` and [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) (or a simple for-loop) for this.

Comment: By the way: You overwrite `mid` without using it. It can only hold one value.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**:  Oops!  Forgot that `m` is a list!

This is what [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) are for.  Because `m` is a list, you'll also need to make use of python's [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) function.  The definition of the new array is:

```
S = [x for x, y in zip(Q, m) if abs(x - y) < d]
```

You'll have to supply `d`.  Also, for completeness:

```
num = len(S)
```

Comment: But there's this error for this code: "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'tuple' and 'tuple'"

Comment: I can't tell what the structure of `Q` or `m` from the code you posted, so I assumed they were simple lists of numeric types.  By the text of the error, it appears to be a list of tuples.  You will either have to post how `Q` and `P` are constructed in your question, or modify the code I posted to put the tuple indices on `x` and `y` in the call `abs(x - y)`.